# Run a Cumulative/Iterative Costum Method on a Column in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, recursion, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Hi I am new to Spark/Scala, I have been trying - AKA failing, to create a column in a spark dataframe based on a particular recursive formula:

Here it is in pseudo code.

```
someDf.col2[0] = 0

for i > 0
someDf.col2[i] = x * someDf.col1[i-1] + (1-x) * someDf.col2[i-1]
```

To dive into more details, here is my starting point:
this dataframe is the result of aggregations both on the level of `dates` and individual `id`'s.

all further calculations have to happen with respect to that particular `id`, and have to take into consideration what happened in the previous week.

to illustrate this I have simplified the values to zeros and ones and removed the multiplier `x` and `1-x`, and I also have initialized the `col2` to zero.

```
var someDf = Seq(("2016-01-10 00:00:00.0","385608",0,0), 
         ("2016-01-17 00:00:00.0","385608",0,0),
         ("2016-01-24 00:00:00.0","385608",1,0),
         ("2016-01-31 00:00:00.0","385608",1,0),
         ("2016-02-07 00:00:00.0","385608",1,0),
         ("2016-02-14 00:00:00.0","385608",1,0),
         ("2016-01-17 00:00:00.0","105010",0,0),
         ("2016-01-24 00:00:00.0","105010",1,0),
         ("2016-01-31 00:00:00.0","105010",0,0),
         ("2016-02-07 00:00:00.0","105010",1,0)
        ).toDF("dates", "id", "col1","col2" )

someDf.show()
```

```
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|               dates|    id|col1|col2|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|2016-01-10 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-02-14 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
```

what I have tried so far vs what is desired

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val date_id_window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(asc("dates")) 

someDf.withColumn("col2", lag($"col1",1 ).over(date_id_window) + 
lag($"col2",1 ).over(date_id_window) ).show()
```

```
+--------------------+------+----+----+ / +--------------------+
|               dates|    id|col1|col2| / | what_col2_should_be|
+--------------------+------+----+----+ / +--------------------+
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|105010|   0|null| / |                   0| 
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0| / |                   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|105010|   0|   1| / |                   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0| / |                   1|
+-------------------------------------+ / +--------------------+
|2016-01-10 00:00:...|385608|   0|null| / |                   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0| / |                   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0| / |                   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|385608|   1|   1| / |                   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|385608|   1|   1| / |                   2|
|2016-02-14 00:00:...|385608|   1|   1| / |                   3|
+--------------------+------+----+----+ / +--------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this with Spark dataframe, I have seen multiple cumulative type computations, but never including the same column, I believe the problem is that the newly computed value for row i-1 is not considered, instead the old i-1 is used which is always 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dataset` should work just fine:

```
val x = 0.1

case class Record(dates: String, id: String, col1: Int)

someDf.drop("col2").as[Record].groupByKey(_.id).flatMapGroups((_,  records) => {
  val sorted = records.toSeq.sortBy(_.dates)
  sorted.scanLeft((null: Record, 0.0)){
    case ((_, col2), record) => (record, x * record.col1 + (1 - x) * col2)
  }.tail
}).select($"_1.*", $"_2".alias("col2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowsBetween` api with the `Window` function you are using and you should have desired output

```
val date_id_window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(asc("dates"))
someDf.withColumn("col2", sum(lag($"col1", 1).over(date_id_window)).over(date_id_window.rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)))
  .withColumn("col2", when($"col2".isNull, lit(0)).otherwise($"col2"))
  .show()
```

Given input `dataframe` as

```
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|               dates|    id|col1|col2|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|2016-01-10 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-02-14 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
```

You should have output dataframe after applying above logic as

```
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|               dates|    id|col1|col2|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|105010|   0|   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|105010|   1|   1|
|2016-01-10 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|385608|   1|   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|385608|   1|   2|
|2016-02-14 00:00:...|385608|   1|   3|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should apply transformations to your dataframe rather than treating it as a `var`.  One way to get what you want is to use Window's `rowsBetween` to cumulatively sum value of `col1` for rows within each window partition through the previous row (i.e. row `-1`):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("dates").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, -1)

val newDF = someDf.
  withColumn(
    "col2", sum($"col1").over(window)
  ).withColumn(
    "col2", when($"col2".isNull, 0).otherwise($"col2")
  ).orderBy("id", "dates")

newDF.show
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|               dates|    id|col1|col2|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|105010|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|105010|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|105010|   0|   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|105010|   1|   1|
|2016-01-10 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-17 00:00:...|385608|   0|   0|
|2016-01-24 00:00:...|385608|   1|   0|
|2016-01-31 00:00:...|385608|   1|   1|
|2016-02-07 00:00:...|385608|   1|   2|
|2016-02-14 00:00:...|385608|   1|   3|
+--------------------+------+----+----+
```